# How is eps() calculated in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, language-agnostic, bit-manipulation, precision

The [`eps`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html) routine in MATLAB essentially returns the positive distance between floating point numbers. It can take an optional argument, too.

My question: How does MATLAB calculate this value? (Does it use a lookup table, or does it use some algorithm to calculate it at runtime, or something else...?)

Related: how could it be calculated in *any* language providing bit access, given a floating point number?

Answer (score 6):

[WIkipedia has quite the page on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon)

Specifically for MATLAB it's 2^(-53), as MATLAB uses double precision by default. Here's the graph:
[image]
It's one bit for the sign, 11 for the exponent and the rest for the fraction.

The [MATLAB documentation on floating point numbers](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html) also show this.

> `d = eps(x)`, where `x` has data type single or double, returns the positive distance from `abs(x)` to the next larger floating-point number of the same precision as `x`.

As not all fractions are equally closely spaced on the number line, different fractions will show different distances to the next floating-point within the same precision. Their bit representations are:

```
1.0 = 0 01111111111 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0.9 = 0 01111111110 1100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101
```

the sign for both is positive (`0`), the exponent is not equal and of course their fraction is vastly different. This means that the next floating point numbers would be:

```
dec2bin(typecast(eps(1.0), 'uint64'), 64) = 0 01111001011 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
dec2bin(typecast(eps(0.9), 'uint64'), 64) = 0 01111001010 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

which are not the same, hence `eps(0.9)~=eps(1.0)`.

Comment: It's actually different for different numbers in MATLAB. Compare `eps(0.9)` to `eps(1.0)`. The Approximation section of the Wikipedia article has a great algorithm, though! I'm wondering if that's actually how MATLAB does it, or if it uses some other approach.

Comment: Of course it's different, since the fraction of `0.9` is not the same as the fraction of `1`. So they are represented differently in bits, and hence the distance to the nearest other bit is also different.

Comment: @jvriesem ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Try `eps(1)` and `eps(1e16)`.

Comment: You said it's 2^(-53) (`1.1102e-16`) for MATLAB. That's the value for `eps(0.9)`, but not for `eps(1.0)`—hence my comment. I know the bit representations are different, causing the distances to be different. I'm wondering how that could be directly calculated, and which way MATLAB does it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some insight into `eps` which will help you to write an algorithm.

See that `eps(1) = 2^(-52)`. Now, say you want to compute the `eps` of `17179869183.9`. Note that, I have chosen a number which is `0.1` less than `2^34` (in other words, something like `2^(33.9999...)`). To compute `eps` of this, you can compute `log2` of the number, which would be ~ `33.99999...` as mentioned before. Take a `floor()` of this number and add it to `-52`, since `eps(1) = 2^(-52)` and the given number `2^(33.999...)`. Therefore, `eps(17179869183.9) = -52+33 = -19`.

If you take a number which is fractionally more than 2^34, e.g., `17179869184.1`, then the log2(eps(`17179869184.1)) = -18`. This also shows that the `eps` value will change for the numbers that are integer powers of your base (or radix), in this case 2. Since `eps` value only changes at those numbers which are integer powers of 2, we take `floor` of the power. You will be able to get the perfect value of `eps` for any number using this. I hope it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB uses (along with other languages) the IEEE754 standard for representing real floating point numbers.

In this format the bits allocated for approximating the actual<sup>1</sup> real number, usually 32 - for single or 64 - for double precision, are grouped into: 3 groups

- 1 bit for determining the sign, s.
- 8 (or 11) bits for exponent, e.
- 23 (or 52) bits for the fraction, f.

Then a real number, n, is approximated by the following three - term - relation:

### n = (-1)<sup>s</sup> * 2<sup>(e - bias)</sup> * (1 + fraction)

where the `bias` offsets negatively<sup>2</sup> the values of the exponent so that they describe numbers between 0 and 1 / (1 and 2) .

Now, the gap reflects the fact that real numbers does not map perfectly to their finite, 32 - or 64 - bit, representations, moreover, a range of real numbers that differ by abs value < eps maps to a single value in computer memory, i.e: if you assign a values `val` to a variable `var_i`

> var_1 = val - offset
> ...
> var_i = val;
> ...
> val_n = val + offset

where

> offset < eps(val) / 2

Then:

> var_1 = var_2 = ... = var_i = ... = var_n.

The gap is determined from the second term containing the exponent (or characteristic):

### 2<sup>(e - bias)</sup>

in the above relation<sup>3</sup>, which determines the *"scale"* of the *"line"* on which the approximated numbers are located, the larger the numbers, the larger the distance between them, the less precise they are and vice versa: the smaller the numbers, the more densely located their representations are, consequently, more accurate.

In practice, to determine the gap of a specific number, `eps(number)`, you can start by adding / subtracting a gradually increasing small number until the initial value of the number of interest changes - this will give you the gap in that (positive or negative) direction, i.e. `eps(number) / 2`.

To check possible implementations of MATLAB's `eps` (or ULP - unit of last place , as it is called in other languages), you could search for ULP implementations either in C, C++ or Java, which are the languages MATLAB is written in.

---

<sup>1. Real numbers are infinitely preciser i.e. they could be written with arbitrary precision, i.e. with any number of digits after the decimal point.</sup>

<sup>2. Usually around the half: in single precision 8 bits mean decimal values from 1 to 2^8 = 256, around the half in our case is: 127, i.e. 2<sup>(e - 127)</sup></sup>

<sup>2. It can be thought that: 2<sup>(e - bias)</sup>, is representing the most significant digits of the number, i.e. the digits that contribute to describe how big the number is, as opposed to the least significant digits that contribute to describe its precise location. Then the larger the term containing the exponent, the smaller the significance of the 23 bits of the fraction.</sup>